# confirm() function is not working in Chrome & FireFox || document.depositNotifInfoForm deprecated

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, struts

In a legacy java struts application, this code in the jsp page is working fine on Internet Explorer but not working in the Chrome & FireFox.

```
<a id="alertSubmit" class="button" href="#" onkeypress="" onclick="javascript:this.blur();depositNotifSubmit();">
<span>
<bean-el:message bundle="${terms}" key="label.submit"/>
</span>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var isSubmit = false;
function depositNotifSubmit()
{
  if (validateFields()) {
if(!isSubmit){
   isSubmit = true;
   doConfirmSubmitAction(document.depositNotifInfoForm, 'depositNotifInput.recip',
'<bean-el:message bundle="${terms}" key="popup.message.continue" />');
    }
}
}

function doConfirmSubmitAction(formObj, action, message)
{
  //if (formObj == null) formObj = document.generalSubmit;
  if (action != null && action != "")
    formObj.action = action;
  if (confirm(message)){
 formObj.submit();
  }else{
 isSubmit = false;
  }
}
```

Expected result (working fine on Internet Explorer) :- After hitting the SUBMIT button it should prompt up a confirm box &  if 'Yes' is selected, then update the changes that is written in the code not provided here.

Actual result :- Working fine in Internet Explorer, showing the confirm pp-up & pressed 'Yes' updating the values. But on Chrome & FireFox, after hitting submit, nor confirm pop-up is showing nor the values are getting updated.

Any help to get this code/scenario  working  on Chrome and Firefox would be appreciated. Find the actual screen-shots for the reference.

After getting the suggestion that document.depositNotifInfoForm has been deprecated & to check the browser console for the error. Attaching the screen shot of the console error for the reference.

Console error :-

```
depositNotifInfo.recip:1034 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at validateFields (depositNotifInfo.recip:1034:64)
    at depositNotifSubmit (depositNotifInfo.recip:980:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (depositNotifInfo.recip:963:147)
validateFields @ depositNotifInfo.recip:1034
depositNotifSubmit @ depositNotifInfo.recip:980
onclick @ depositNotifInfo.recip:963
```

[Browser console error screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3mWL.jpg)

Comment: That I know of, `document.depositNotifInfoForm` has long been deprecated and removed.

Comment: Open the browser console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`) and see if there's any error. If there is kindly edit your question with the pasted error.

Comment: depositNotifInfo.recip:1034 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at validateFields (depositNotifInfo.recip:1034:64)
    at depositNotifSubmit (depositNotifInfo.recip:980:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (depositNotifInfo.recip:963:147)
validateFields @ depositNotifInfo.recip:1034
depositNotifSubmit @ depositNotifInfo.recip:980
onclick @ depositNotifInfo.recip:963


Find the screen-shot for clear idea in the edited question

Comment: Could you edit your question with the error?

Comment: Added the console error for your reference in the edited question above

Comment: Could you suggest how can this problem be solved & scenario be done /alternative of document.*  ?

Comment: I'm not sure what functionality you wish to achieve. Can you explain what you want?

Comment: Expected result (working fine on Internet Explorer) :- After hitting the SUBMIT button it should prompt up a confirm box & if 'Yes' is selected, then update the changes that is written in the code not provided here. (Code from submit button & the function called on hitting the submit button is provided above). Actual result :- Working fine in Internet Explorer, showing the confirm pp-up & pressed 'Yes' updating the values. But on Chrome & FireFox, after hitting submit, nor confirm pop-up is showing nor the values are getting updated. So want to achieve the same functionality on chrome & fireox

Comment: As mentioned that ‘document.depositNotifInfo’ is deprecated long back, what exactly do you mean by that. Have ‘document.*’ is deprecated? Because if you see the code snippet provided above, depositNotifInfoFrom is the name of my <form-bean> specified in my strut.XML file

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding. So it was manually defined not by the browser?

Comment: Yes.. it is the name of my bean defined in strut.xml.. The main culprit i can find is the confirm() function, which when clicked 'ok' returns true & submit the required form. when selected 'cancel' returns false and set the isSubmit as false.
The main problem is that it is working fine on internet explorer. i.e., the confirm pop-up is shown and accordingly performing the task. But on chrome the confirm pop-up is not is shown thus, it seems falling & setting the isSubmit as false..
Could you suggest any alternative of confirm()? Which true or false like confirm()